# Debugger doesn't work: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-10, vscode-debugger

I am using Python in VS Code on Windows 10. When I run debugger, the following message appears in terminal:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive - Akademia Górniczo-Hutnicza im. Stanisawa Staszica w Krakowie\\AGH\\Programowanie\\python_scripts\\testuje\\prosty.py'
```

And indeed, this is not-existing path. But why? In the next line in terminal the correct path appears:

```
PS C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Akademia Górniczo-Hutnicza im. Stanisława Staszica w Krakowie\AGH\Programowanie\python_scripts\testuje>
```

The debugger changes the correct path to the incorrect one?
When I run the script without debugging, then everything works fine.

EDIT:
The full terminal information:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Akademia Górniczo-Hutnicza im. Stanisława Staszica w Krakowie\AGH\Programowanie\python_scripts\testuje>  & 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1246542782\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '50663' '--' 'c:\Users\user\OneDrive - Akademia Górniczo-Hutnicza im. Stanisawa Staszica w Krakowie\AGH\Programowanie\python_scripts\testuje\prosty.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1246542782\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1246542782\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.9.1246542782\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 267, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 237, in _get_code_from_file
    with io.open_code(decoded_path) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive - Akademia Górniczo-Hutnicza im. Stanisawa Staszica w Krakowie\\AGH\\Programowanie\\python_scripts\\testuje\\prosty.py'
PS C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Akademia Górniczo-Hutnicza im. Stanisława Staszica w Krakowie\AGH\Programowanie\python_scripts\testuje>
```

Comment: I tried running the debugger in a piece of code in my OneDrive folder. The code ran normally but the debugger failed. Try moving your code to a local folder and try again. If you want backup your code, consider using a version control service, such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) instead. The free tier is quite good for non-commercial/academic usage.

Comment: In Visual Studio (not Code!), the debugger runs normally. Hence, the problem is with Visual Studio Code. There should be some solution to run it from OneDrive folder.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to open  the folder C:\Users\user\OneDrive - Akademia Górniczo-Hutnicza im. Stanisława Staszica w Krakowie\AGH\Programowanie\python_scripts\testuje in vscode then run the debugger

Comment: It was opened. I added the full terminal information to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces in path may cause recognition errors.

Please remove the spaces in your path or rename your folder to a simple one, still without spaces, see if the error goes away.

Comment: I know that renaming will help - everything is ok, when I run this from desktop. The thing is, that I can't rename the folder, as the name was given by One Drive. This is my work One Drive account. Is there any other solution? Debugger in Visual Studio (not Code) works fine from this folder.

Comment: @Poiuyt, I rename my folder to be as same as yours, open it in vscode as current working directory, the debugger works fine. How about [resetting vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code), is there any difference?

Comment: I have this problem on two of my computers, and VSC was installed about one month ago, hence I am sure it won't help. Moreover, someone wrote below my first post, that had the same problem in his OneDrive folder. So, maybe it is related to OneDrive.

Comment: @Poiuyt. Sorry that i can't reproduce your question, you may ask in [vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues) for more help.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for recommending the site, I will look at it.

Comment: I have ask on vscode-python, here is the link: https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/740 There are no solutions yet, but I figured out the the problem occurs when a folder name contains the letter 'ł', which is the polish character. So, the problem is not related to one drive.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove spaces. That's fixed my FileError.
Be cautious on spacing.
Save lifes!!